# $wpdb class updating meta_value using Ajax

Tags: post-meta, ajax, meta-query

I am trying to create a way to change the order of posts using a meta_key / meta_value that is updated using jQuery ui-sortable.

I'm already using menu_order in the same way but need to create a way to preview the new order before saving the new menu_order values.

My Ajax function that is not working:

```
function wnd_preview_item_order() {
    global $wpdb;
    $order = explode(',', $_POST['order']);
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($order as $item_id) {
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->postmeta, array( 'meta_key' => '_wnd_pre_order', 'meta_value' => $counter ), array( 'ID' => $item_id) );
        $counter++;
    }
    die(1);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_item_sort', 'wnd_preview_item_order');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_item_sort', 'wnd_preview_item_order');
```

I'm able to update the menu_order with no problems using a similar Ajax function but I'm stuck on changing the meta_key value.

Sortable js:

#### Update: I made some adjustments to the js to save the order on click.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $( "#<?php echo $catID; ?>-sortable" ).sortable({
        cursor:'move',
        items:'.lineitem',
        placeholder:'sortable-placeholder',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        helper: 'clone',
        opacity: 0.65
    });
    $("#<?php echo $catID; ?>-save-order").bind( "click", function() {
       $.post( ajaxurl, { action:'item_sort', order: $( "#<?php echo $catID; ?>-sortable" ).sortable('toArray').toString() },
       function() {
       $("#<?php echo $catID; ?>-ajax-response").html('<div class="message updated fade"><p>Post Order Updated</p></div>');
       $("#<?php echo $catID; ?>-ajax-response div").delay(3000).hide("slow");
    });
       });

});
```

My Query to display the posts using the meta_value orderby:

```
$exclude =  $GLOBALS['current_id'];
            if ($count >= 4 ) : $ppp = 4; else : $ppp = 7; endif;
            $args = array(
            'cat' => $category->term_id,
            'meta_key'  => '_wnd_pre_order',
            'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'post__not_in' => array($exclude),
            'posts_per_page' => $ppp
        );
        $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

#### Update:

This is the Ajax function for changing the menu_order which does work:

```
function wnd_save_item_order() {
     global $wpdb;
    $order = explode(',', $_POST['order']);
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($order as $item_id) {
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array( 'menu_order' => $counter ), array( 'ID' => $item_id) );
        $counter++;
    }
    die(1);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just update the menu_order column in the wp_posts table?  This could save you considerable work as you can just orderby menu_order.

Comment: Well what's the error (the value of `e`) ? Just so you know, you're requesting a json response, but the wnd_preview_item_order function is not sending any json encoded data.

Comment: @BrianFegter I am using menu_order but my client wants the ability to preview the page with the new order before saving.

Comment: @OneTrickPony It was alerting success.

Comment: Just a note: Don't `die(1)`, as this sometimes prevents throwing a proper `0` or `-1` on return. Just do an `exit;`, which is also a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  So admin-ajax.php will throw the 0 or -1?

Comment: Is the question still relevant or can be closed?

Comment: @Chris_O Yes, _afaik_ it will. Could you please move your solution to an answer?